# Grafana - reverse proxy auth with nginx

Tags: authentication, nginx, grafana, reverse-proxy

I’m trying to set up reverse proxy authentification so that I can whitelist my kiosk pc in order to forward them to my grafana dashboard without an authentification prompt. Other users which are not whitelisted should use the azureAD login prompt (which is already working).

My problem is that the whitelisted ips from nginx get forwarded to the grafana login page but not logged in (basic auth is enabled) and I can’t figure out my problem.

Here is my grafana config:

```
#################################### Auth Proxy ######### 
[auth.proxy]
enabled = true 
header_name = X-WEBAUTH-USER 
header_property = username 
auto_sign_up = true 
sync_ttl = 60 
whitelist = <myWhiteListedIP>
headers = 
headers_encoded = false 
enable_login_token = true
```

Here is my nginx config:

```
# HTTPS server 
server { 
    listen 443 ssl
    server_name <myGrafanaServer>; 
    
    ssl_certificate "C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\<...>
    ssl_certificate_key "C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\<...>

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:lm;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; 

    location / {
        allow <myWhiteListedlP>;
        deny all; 
    
        proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-WEBAUTH-USER $remote_user;
        proxy_set_header Authorization ""; 
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

So my understanding of the whole situation is that nginx is responsible for my authentification (in my case white listed ips) and I only have to forward the user with the X-WEBAUTH-USER header to automatically get logged in. Please correct me if I am understanding it incorrectly.

Comment: Please don't use images for configs, logs, but use formatted code text.

Comment: Changed it thanks.

Comment: Authentication should provide user identity, which ip whitelisting is not doing. So I would say it is authorization, not authentication. It is not clear, what variable remote_user contains and why you are sending empty authorizations header. Anyway, enable devug logs and check Grafana logs. I guess remote_user is empty, so Grafana doesn't have any identity, so redirect to login is correct and safe option.